# In Force.com IDE lost all my projects

Tags: salesforce-id, eclipse

I started my Force.com IDE and go an error message saying unable to load metadata for one of my class. I did a refresh and everything disappeared. I then tried creating a new project, and got following error.[image]

I haven't changed my password and I am able to login using my current credentials.

Not sure how to fix this.

I have even tried re-installing the IDE but same error.

Comment: Are you using your security token? And you haven't confused your sandbox/production logins?

Comment: Can you connect using same credentials on login.salesforce.com? Did you set the security token ?

Comment: What do you mean "everything disappeared"? Maybe eclipse doesn't see the projects (or somehow "plugins" directory got corrupted) but check on the filesystem whether your projects are in directory called workspace? If they physically are there you'd just have to reimport them to IDE (maybe make backup first). Other than that - looks like sec. token problem but check also `.log` file in eclipse...

Comment: I did a reimport and it worked like a charm. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of figured out why this happened. My machine was running on JDK 7, I did an uninstall of JDK 7 and installed JDK 6. Force.com IDE is working fine now.

Comment: Cool, glad my comment could be of assistance :) Please consider marking answer as accepted so it goes "off the radar" and improves our stats!

Comment: This is a good answer. JDK7 is problematic indeed, but is not obvious to developers to uninstall JDF7 and install JDK6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some metadata which once existed do not exist any more. Here is the simplest way to solve most Eclipse problems, although it is **extremely crude** and time consuming in case the project contents have a lot to be downloaded.

1. Make a backup <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> of your code/files from the *Workspace* and store/save/paste <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> the code in a different folder using Windows Explorer.
2. Delete your *Workspace* using Windows Explorer.
3. Recreate/download/import the project again using Eclipse / Force.com IDE.